# Injectivity implies left inverse

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse, inverse-function

1)If $f:X→Y$ is injective then $f$ has left inverse.
=> Define $g:Y→X$ s.t.
$g(y)= x$ when $y=f(x)$ and
$X\circ$ otherwise
Clearly $g\circ f =Ix$ and we are done.

The doubt is to imply this in example.
What I have understood so far is I m gonna explain in this example.
Consider $X={1, 2, 3}$ and $Y ={1,2,3,4}$
Given $f: X→Y$ s.t. $f(x)= x+1$ is an injective map.
We need to find the left inverse of $f$
For that define $g:Y→X$ s.t.
$g(y)= x$ when $y=x+1$ and
$1$ otherwise
Then $g$ is our left inverse here as $gof=Ix$

But we can define our 'otherwise' elements as $2$ or $3$ which will also be inverse of $f$  which is contradiction to the fact that if f has left inverse then it must be Unique.

I know I m misunderstanding something  but not able to know actually what is wrong here ... majorly the problem is to map 'otherwise' terms.

Comment: The left inverse $g$ does not need to be unique, I think that's what's confusing you. So your example is still legitimate.

Comment: @jasnee  Let g and h be inverse of f:A→B.   Let any y€B let g(y)=a and h(y)= b then y=f(a) and y=f(b ).  Since f has left inverse => f is injective→ a=b => g(y)=h(y). As y is arbitrary g=h ?

Comment: It is not true that then $y=f(a)$ and $y=f(b)$. You somehow used that $f(g(y))=y$ and $f(h(y))=y$, but you do not know that. In fact, this is even false in this case: if you take $y=1 \in Y$ as in your original question, and you define $g$ as above and $h$ exactly as $g$, except that $h$ maps 1 to 2, then you get $f(g(1))=2 \neq 3 = f(h(1))$.

Comment: Yes thats where i was confusing since long. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!